# count height and resize for each article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my markup:

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content_expander">
    {newsrow.MESSAGE}
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="expand">Rozwiń</a>
  </div>
```

Which I'm using to list my posts from forum.

`.content div` height is 500px by default, `.content_expander` is the article height (which is sometimes higher than parent div).

What I want achieve is being able to expand and collapse `.content div` to show/hide whole post.

So there is what I have tried already:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("article .content").each(function() {
    var boxHeight = 500;
    var insideHeight = $(this).find(".content_expander").height();
    //alert(insideHeight);
    if(boxHeight<insideHeight) {
        $(this).children(".expand").css({
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline-block'     
    }).animate({opacity:1},600);
    }

  });
    $('.expand').click(function(){
        var elementToChange = $(this).parent().find(".content_expander");
        newHeight = elementToChange.height();

        elementToChange.parent().animate({ 
        height: newHeight + 'px',
      }, 500 );
        $(this).addClass('collapse');
        $(this).removeClass('expand');
        $(this).html('Collapse');
        return false;
    });
    $('.collapse').click(function(){
        var elementToChange = $(this).parent().find(".content_expander");
        newHeight = elementToChange.height();

        elementToChange.parent().animate({ 
        height: '500px',
      }, 500 );
        $(this).addClass('expand');
        $(this).removeClass('collapse');
        $(this).html('Expand');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Would you guys help me to improve that? :/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are the jQuery .slideDown and .slideUp functions, which can easily be added to a click event listener:

```
$('.expand').on('click', function() {
   var parent = $(this).parent().find(".content_expander");
   var parentVisibility = parent.css('display');
   if ( parentVisibility == 'none' ) {
      parent.slideDown(500); 
      $(this).text('Collapse');
   }
   else {
      parent.slideUp(500);      
      $(this).text('Expand');
   }
});
```

I think that's what you're looking for (if not, please do inform me). Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkvA/9jTUM/1/

Comment: Yeah, i know about that way, but i want to keep that "500px part" all the time visible, and IF there is more content toggle it up/down.